# Mosca and mqtt don't get messages from browserfied mqtt web client

Tags: node.js, websocket, browserify, webpack, mqtt

Following the tips from [MQTT-over-Websockets](https://github.com/mcollina/mosca/wiki/MQTT-over-Websockets) I tried to add to this alredy working setup.
server(broker)

```
var mosca = require('mosca')
var settings = {
  port: 1883,
  persistence: mosca.persistence.Memory,
  http: {port: 3333, bundle: true, static: './'}  
};
var server = new mosca.Server(settings, function() {
  console.log('Mosca server is up and running')
});
server.published = function(packet, client, cb) {
  if (packet.topic.indexOf('echo') === 0) {
    return cb();
  }
  var newPacket = {
    topic: 'echo/' + packet.topic,
    payload: packet.payload,
    retain: packet.retain,
    qos: packet.qos
  };
  console.log('newPacket', newPacket);
  server.publish(newPacket, cb);
}
```

client2.js

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
client = mqtt.createClient(1883, 'localhost');
client.subscribe('presence');
client.on('message', function(topic, message) {
    console.log(message.toString());
});
console.log('Client started...');
```

client1.js

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
client = mqtt.createClient(1883, 'localhost');
client.subscribe('presence');
console.log('Client publishing.. ');
client.publish('presence', 'Client 10 is alive.. Test Ping! ' + Date());
client.end();
```

So I want to get a web client working and I followed the instructions in [mqtt in browser w webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#browser) to create browserMqtt.js

```
cd node_modules/mqtt
npm install . // install dev dependencies 
webpack mqtt.js ./browserMqtt.js --output-library mqtt
```

and used it in a webpage mimiking what the node client2.js already does.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>webmqtt</title>
    <script src="./dist/browserMqtt.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>
    <h1>hello</h1>
    <script>
        client = mqtt.connect({ host: 'localhost', port: 3333 });
        client.subscribe('presence');
        client.on('message', function(topic, payload) {
            console.log(message.toString())
        });
        client.publish('presence', 'Web Client is alive.. Test Ping! ' + Date());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's publish message isn't showing up on the other clients and it doesn't get the messages it is subscribed to. It does however cause a new packet to arrive at the server with what looks like the browser client's id.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to the fact that the message callback function uses payload as the variable name but you use message in the function.

```
message.toString()
```

it should be

```
payload.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your using the wrong port number on the client side. It should be 3333 not 1883

1883 is for native MQTT, the config you have shown for the Websocket connection is port 3333

You should probably also include the protocol in the object you pass to connect

```
 client = mqtt.connect({ host: 'localhost', port: 3333, protocol: 'ws' });
```